# Python selenium getting error message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, binaryfiles

I want to scrape a page using python (3.10.4) but need to click a button first that opens the complete text I need. It seams impossible to do with *requests* as it does not lead to a new link, so I am trying to do it with *selenium* (3.141.0). I get errors from trying to configure the chromedriver.

I am not working locally, but from github codespaces. I added *chromedriver.exe* to my repository.

**Directory**

project

│

├── notebooks

```
   ├── current_file.py
```

├── chromedriver.exe

**Code**

I first tried this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('../chromedriver.exe')
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

but it raises error in line 2: `WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home`

So by answers I found in other post I tried:

```
import os
os.chmod('../chromedriver.exe', 755)

from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('../chromedriver.exe')
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

but raises error in line 2: `OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '../chromedriver.exe'`

Also tried

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

but raises error in line 3: `WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary`

---

**Update**

I was wrongly using chromedriver for windows, when github-codespaces is a linux environment. Now chmod works, but the next line

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('../chromedriver')
```

raises `WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary`. Can someone tell me if the path is correct? Is it needed not a relative path but the absolute, meaning I need to intall in chromedriver in the machine? If the latest, how can I do it?

Please help! I really need to figure this out to be able to continue.

Comment: do you have chrome browser installed?

Comment: Usage of `os.chmod()`  and paths indicate that you are either using mac or linux ? But then the chromedriver binary, you have `chromedriver.exe` which is the windows version of chromedriver .. And you get "Exec format error" which *again* feels like you are trying to use windows chromedriver on non-windows OS. Verify first that you are using the correct webdriver..

Comment: Yes, I have chrome browser installed. @rasjani you are right, Im mixing os. I should use  Linux given that github codespaces is in a linux environment. Ill try that and let you know!

Comment: I update my question. Now Im getting 'WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary'